# Understanding GDELT

Tags: bigdata, gdelt

I'm new to Gdelt world and i try to understand 3 databases, namely events, Mentions, GKG. they can be combined to each other through their ID. but my question is regarding Mentions database.

where were these articles mentioned actually?

as example:

```
Column1 GLOBALEVENTID   EventTimeDate   MentionTimeDate MentionType MentionSourceName  MentionIdentifier    SentenceID  Actor1CharOffset    Actor2CharOffset    ActionCharOffset    InRawText   Confidence  MentionDocLen   MentionDocTone  MentionDocTranslationInfo   Extras
 1046987    518983034   20160308094500  20160308103000  1             nytimes.com    http://www.nytimes.com/aponline/2016/03/08/world/europe/ap-eu-germany-volkswagen.html  1   56  76  117 1   100 920 -9.219858156
```

i can see the source and with the help of Id i can check for the event but not where it was mentioned?

does anyone have any experience with it?

Answer (score 0):

In Mentions, you have where the event is mentioned, which is the link provided. Are you asking about the exact location where the event occured, such as geo coordinates?

You have in data when the event occured, and when it is mentioned, and you have the media link as well.

In their website, its stated that:

"Beginning with April 1, 2013, files are created daily and records are stored by the date the event was found in the world's news media rather than the date it occurred (97%+ of events are reported within 24 hours of happening, but a small number of events each day are past events being mentioned for the first time - if an event has been seen before it will not be included again)"

Comment: no, i meant in which websites these articles (which are websites) were mentioned?

Comment: @MostafaBouzari, here is a link that explains the columns of GDELT dataset in detail: https://mind-node.net/gdelt-mentions/ . I assume you are asking where exactly the mention is inside the articles.